# Generate nested dictionary from pairs

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have an input dictionary:

```
d={'AM-tv': 1.2,
  'AM-rs': 1.3,
  'AM-pq': 1.2,
  'BR-MN': 1.3,
  'BR-tN': 1.3,
  'BR-tq': 1.4}
```

Expected Output

```
d={'AM':{'tv':1.2,'rs':1.3,'pq':1.2},'BR':{'MN':1.3,'tN':1.3,'tq':1.4}
```

Is there any way to produce nested dictionary from pairs of the input dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to split the keys and use `dict.setdefault` to initialize inner dicts:

```py
out = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    o,i = k.split('-')
    out.setdefault(o, {})[i] = v
```

Output:

```py
{'AM': {'tv': 1.2, 'rs': 1.3, 'pq': 1.2},
 'BR': {'MN': 1.3, 'tN': 1.3, 'tq': 1.4}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could loop over the `items()` which will give you key/value pairs, `split()` the key and assign. `setdefault` is helpful here to initialize the inner dicts with a new empty dict when it sees an outer key for the first time:

```
d = {
    'AM-tv': 1.2,
    'AM-rs': 1.3,
    'AM-pq': 1.2,
    'BR-MN': 1.3,
    'BR-tN': 1.3,
    'BR-tq': 1.4
}

new_d = {}

for k, v in d.items():
    k1, k2 = k.split('-')
    new_d.setdefault(k1, {})[k2] = v
```

`new_d` will be:

```
{'AM': {'tv': 1.2, 'rs': 1.3, 'pq': 1.2},
 'BR': {'MN': 1.3, 'tN': 1.3, 'tq': 1.4}}
```